# How to determine number of boost for calculating Krippendorff’s Alpha?

Tags: spss, boosting, reliability, software

I'm using the SPSS macro for computing [Krippendorff’s Alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krippendorff%27s_alpha), developed by [Andrew F. Hayes & Klaus Krippendorff](https://doi-org.ezproxy.lib.nctu.edu.tw/10.1080/19312450709336664).
One argument needed is the units of bootstrapping, and I did not find formula for calculating how many bootstrapping we need so far.

In their paper, they stated that 5 observers judging 40 units require 10,000 boostrap, but I cannot see why.

How to determine number of boost for calculating Krippendorff’s Alpha in general ?

Their example SPSS Syntax:

```
kalpha judges = obsa obsb obsc obsd obse /level = 1 /detail = 1 /boot = 10000.
```

Comment: Do I need to add more details about this question?

Comment: @Galen, do you know anything about this problem?